# AWS RDS - MySQL to SQL Server Linked Server - How To / Alternatives

Tags: mysql, sql-server, amazon-rds, linked-server

**Situation:**

I have a MySQL database and SQL Server database, both in AWS RDS. SQL Server is 2016.  I need to be able to select data from the MySQL db (in SQL Server).  Before moving to RDS, I was able to accomplish this by creating a Linked Server in SQL Server using the MySQL Connector/ODBC.

My understanding is that ODBC driver must be installed/setup on the SQL Server (box), which isn't possible with RDS.

I looked at CLR, but not sure if that will be a viable route either ([from reading online](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/8zbqvw/sql_server_2017_clr_support/)) with RDS (?).

Any ideas/experience on how I can select data from the MySQL database in SQL Server when both databases are housed in RDS?  The solution doesn't need to be high speed and probably only needs to be used 100 to 200 times.

Only thing I can think of is to create a cache table in SQL, use my application layer to copy the MySQL data to the SQL cache table, and then use that cache table instead of MySQL directly.

Thanks!

Comment: What solution did you end up using?  I am in a similar position.

Comment: @JoeJ - We didn't end up finding an easy solution.  In the end, we ended up using an EC2-based MS SQL Server installation to create the MySQL linked server on (where we could install the MySQL ODBC).  And where we needed to go MySQL RDS -> MSSQL RDS, we remained limited to using an application layer to create the bridge.